# What format must the 'file' parameter be in the createItem function in arcgis-rest-portal?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I am attempting to upload a file (I have tried shapefile.zip and GeoJSON) using the createItem function from arcgis-rest-portal. The file is local and not passed via a form. Do I pass a local path? Or a byte array? Whatever I try does not seem to work.

```js
createItem({
    item: {
        title: 'Test',
        type: 'Shapefile',
        description: 'Test upload'
    },
    file: '../data/test.zip' // What goes here?
    filename: 'test.zip',
    authentication,
    multipart: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using:
`data = fs.createReadStream('../data/test.json')`
Then passing `data` to the `file:` parameter and removing the `multipart: true` line. I thought it *must* be multipart in order to upload a file according to docs. Any light on this would be greatly appreciated.